# Apache Wicket live preview changes in HTML and CSS

Tags: java, wicket

I am starting with Apache Wicket framework. I developed SPA applications until now where I was able to watch changes in realtime. In wicket is frontend rendered on server, so can there are some way how to get live preview of my code?

I stared project from scratch from wicket page where I have only HomePage, and let's say I build and run that project with commands `mvn clean package` and `mvn jetty:run`

Now I need change some css, f.e. background color. This css I have included by default with link in HomePage like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
</head>
```

But I don't see that change in running code, I already have to stop server, rebuild project, a run server for every little change ... how to avoid these unnecessary steps? I am using wicket 8, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use embedded Jetty. [Wicket Quickstart Maven archetype](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) provides everything pre-configured. You just have to run Start.java in your IDE and every change in HTML/CSS/JS files in the webapp/ folder will be autodetected. For the files which are in the classpath  (src/main/java or src/main/resources) you will need to compile the Maven module. This happens automatically on every change in Eclipse. In IDEA you have to do it manually via Build menu -> Make module.

Comment: All what you say I did. I am using embedded jetty and run it with mvn jetty:run ... now when I change something in style.css this change isn't reflected to running app in browser. I also tried build module, build project, Ctrl + f10 to update resources and nothing helped. I am using IDEA IDE ... did I miss something ?

Comment: I also added init-param into web.xml where param-name is configuration and param-value is development

Comment: I said that you need to use Start.java from the quickstart, not jetty:run.